# Ember Simple Auth with Multiple Devise Scopes

Tags: authentication, ember.js, devise, ember-simple-auth

I have the following scenario:

1. Rails app with User and Admin devise models, so I have two scopes.
2. Created on ember app on router:

   ```
   Router.map(function() {
     this.route('panel', function() {
       this.route('login');
       this.route('logout');
     });
     this.route('admin', function() {
       this.route('login');
       this.route('logout');
     });
   });
   ```
3. I'm using `jj-abrams` branch once my app is Ember 2.0

Both authenticating on `/users/sign_in` and `/admins/sign_in`

I followed steps on https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/tree/master/packages/ember-simple-auth-devise#server-side-setup and authentication is working.

Ember is hitting the right urls after creating authenticators and adapters, but the problem is that ESA just have one session service. Once user or admin is logged in `session.isAuthenticated` is true and I don't know which scopes are logged in.

Which is the best way to proceed:

1. Add a `role` on user reply and set on session
2. Create a new session for admin user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problema creating 3 [authenticators](https://github.com/fernandes/ember-auth-web/tree/master/app/authenticators) for each scope, and I handle each one.

It is a particular solution once I don't use other authenticators (OAuth2), but now I can check if `authenticator:user`, `authenticator:admin`, `authenticator:manager` was used on to login.

I have created checks on routes, so user can only access his panel, admin can access user and admin panel, and manager can access the whole system.

I've posted the ember and the API on github:

- https://github.com/fernandes/ember-auth-web for the ember
- https://github.com/fernandes/ember-auth-api for the devise api

ps: I think would be better to create sessions for each scope, but I don't know how to do it (and if its better or not), in this solution you can login one scope at once (not like devise on rails you can log with many scopes at once).

Comment: Those github repos no longer exist.